# Nautilus with Two tabs takes up 300MB memory?

Tags: nautilus, memory

There are currently two tabs opened in Nautilus. It has been running for quite a while, there  have been more opened and closed before, and there have been switching between directories using bookmarks before. Now Nautilus takes up about 300MB memory shown in "Memory" column in system monitor. This happened quite often. I wonder if it is reasonable?

If I exit Nautilus, and restart it, and open just two tabs, the memory used is just 16.3MB.

Thanks!

Comment: A bug report could possibly be reported citing a potential memory leak if the memory continues to increase through use.

Comment: This sounds like a memory leak to me...